# Applying a MouseEvent to a node within a GridPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently creating a Boggle game in Java, and I am on the final stage of the game, adding a GUI using JavaFX. To simulate the 4X4 tray of dice in Boggle, I have a GridPane that contains 16 TilePane objects (each TilePane is an HBox showing the die letter and background color,) and all I am trying to do is be able to apply an action on the Tile when it is clicked by the user (ie change its background color to indicate it is being selected.)

I have no idea where to start on adding the MouseEvent, and currently all I have is a 4X4 board of "dice," my TilePane objects.

Do I need to "capture" a node by using getSource() and cast it as a TilePane object, then apply setOnMouseClicked() with a MouseEvent to change its background color?

Comment: Why not call [setOnMouseClicked](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseClicked%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) for each child of each TilePane?

Comment: The children of my GridPane are the 16 TilePane objects. I don't know how to "select" or capture the specific TilePane node from the GridPane when it is clicked on, and apply a setSelected() method I have created within the TilePane class that changes its background color to that clicked on node.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the TilePane objects to your GridPane?

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you guys anyways